# How to open desktop shortcuts in non-default browser - without address bar & menubar visible

Tags: windows, firefox, shortcuts

I have a shortcut on my Desktop which points to an internet address.Usually it opens in my default browser which is chrome.

But I want to open it on Firefox without the address bar and menu bar visible.

And if possible, I'd like to define a custom window size for Firefox too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got was to start Firefox with a new profile, remove (most) buttons, and then create a shortcut not to the URL, but to the FF executable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -profile d:\temp\newprofile -height 400 -width 400 http://www.google.com`. See [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) for more options.

The address bar cannot be removed in this way, but it [seems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/939601) that you can do that by adding `#nav-bar { display: none !important; }` to *userChrome.css* which should be in the *chrome* subfolder of the profile folder. If it's not there, create it manually and restart Firefox.

The -no-remote option makes sure that the specified profile will be used, even if Firefox is already running under another profile.

Comment: @Arjan Not exactly intuitively named, but yes, -no-remote does exactly that. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanx for answer and i did as you said but still address bar is not hide

Comment: I just tried the instruction in the provided link (again) to make sure it works, and it does. Note that you need to put that line in a file called _userChrome.css_ in a subfolder named _chrome_, which does not yet exist in new profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

- Click Start
- Click Programs
- Click Mozilla Firefox
- Right-click the Mozilla Firefox icon and select Send To and then select Desktop (create shortcut)
- Right-click the new shortcut and select Properties
- On the Shortcut tab, click the Target field and move the cursor to the end of all the text
- Enter a single space and then enter your URL URL_FF
- Click Apply
- Click the General tab
- In the text field at the top, give your shortcut an appropriate name
- Click OK

Taken Source :

http://scls.typepad.com/techbits/2010/04/when-you-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-url-it-is-going-to-launch-the-url-with-your-default-web-browser-what-do-you-do-if-y.html

Hope that helps

Comment: That may open it in firefox, but how does it remove the menu and address bar?